# Open form in Add mode, Saved, then placed in Edit Mode - Refresh or Requery?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I OpenForm using the acFormAdd property, and using buttons, allow the user to Save the record, and while still in the same instance of the form they can click an Edit button to set `me.AllowEdits=True`.  (Also, me.newrecords is false at this point)  While in edit mode, they can click a button that runs a shell script that updates the underlying "new" records data.   While continuing further entry and attempts to save, this causes "Data Has been Changed" errors as the record is now out of sync with the SQL database.  (since the shell script changed data)

So the thought was to `me.Requery` the data after the "Shell" is run, but this causes problems.  Although I can see that the record has been saved in the underlying table (and no longer "new") the form still thinks it's in "Add" type form.

So then I tried changing me.allowadditions=false, thinking it should act like a form that was opened in Edit mode (where I have no issues running a requery - i.e. form was opened using acFormEdit).

So I scrapped trying to change me.allowadditions and in the interim, I've applied a bandaid after the "shell" that seems to work okay.

```
vba.createobject("XXX.shell").run(blablabla)
If Me.AllowAdditions Then
    Me.Refresh
Else
    Me.Requery
End If
```

Subsequent updates of controls do not conflict.  This seems like an okay solution, but curious...

Why does a form in "add" mode, but subsequently changed in the manner I've described, not truly act like a form/record in edit mode?  It seems like it still thinks the current record is not truly "added" yet.  Although the me.newrecord is shwing false.

Throughout my database I give the user the choice to open a from using New or Edit.  Then on subsequent save I would simply like to implement an allowadditions=false (note we don't always force forms closed).  This should allow me to account for any instance where a form might require a requery of data, regardless of their being in add/edit mode.

Anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Me personally, I always close and re-open forms that have been opened in "Add" mode to avoid situations just like this.  Access is very quirky.

Comment: As for 'why' MS Access's behavior does not seem to make sense?  I give you my standard answer: "Because Microsoft."  :-)